# Force a section to always print on odd pages in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, footer, show-hide

I have an invoice that runs off of a crystal report and I want to tweak it, but can't seem to figure it out.

I have paper that has a sticker at the bottom (to put on boxes and such). I have a label which is a report footer on the report that always prints at the bottom of the page so that it will fit on the sticker. On the back of the invoice I print the return policy and other information so we can save on paper. The invoice has a list of items and prices and normally there is no problem. However, every once in a while there are so many items that it forces the label onto the next page (which is the back of the sticker).

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |        Item 1       Price                                         |
    |        Item 2       Price                                         |
    |        Item 3       Price                                         |
    |        Item 4       Price                                         |
    |        Item 5       Price                                         |
    |        Item 6       Price                                         |
    |        etc.                                                       |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                            Sticker                                |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    |                                                                   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Q:Is there a way to force a report footer to print only on odd pages so that the label will always be on a sticker?

Things I've tried:

1. On the label section I've tried the "New Page Before" if pagenumber mod 2 = 0
2. Creating a new report footer section above the label that's the same size as the label that prints a new page after if pagenumber mod 2 = 0 and is suppressed if pagenumber mod 2 = 1. I've tried a couple of variations of this, i.e. making the section always print on the bottom of the page, forcing the label to print of the bottom of the next page and stuff like that but none of it worked.

Perhaps I'm on the right track and missing something simple, or maybe I'm not even close. Either way any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, try this solution

Move the Sticker to the Page Footer and hide it on odd pages.

Steps: 
Open report desing mode

1. copy the sticker to  page footer.
2. go to Section expert
3. Suppress [x-2] on formula and place if pagenumber mod 2 = 0
4. run report

Comment: The point being that a REPORT footer always comes at the end of the report, but a page footer can come on any page

Comment: I didn't even think about the page footer. I tried it out and it worked great. Thanks for the great idea